# Curl post file PHP Notice: Array to string conversion

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста, как передать файл при помощи curl post без предупреждения php что $data_curl это массив `PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion...`

```
$data_curl = array('files' => array());
$data_curl = $data_curl + array(
  'file'.$i => curl_file_create($tmpfile, $_FILES['files']['type'][$i], $filename)
);
$ch = curl_init('https://google.com/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Accept: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_curl);
curl_exec($ch);
```

`json_encode` и `http_build_query` не отправляют файл.

Comment: Зачем вы устанавливаете appplication/json если передаете файлы? Откуда берется $i, и какую часть этого кода вы прооводите в цикле? Зачем вам files, если вы туда ничего не пишите. file_i у вас не массивы, как требует документация

Comment: @teran есть пример как отправить несколько файлов как требует документация?

Comment: примера нет. но устраните вопросы которые я задал, мб и заработает